# Zuul dynamic routing

Tags: netflix-zuul

I am trying to use Zuul as an API Gateway, in one particular scenario I have to change URL, based on data coming from client. I can do most of the things using "pre" filter but so far I'm unable to read the configured URL in the route.

This is how my route looks like:

```
zuul:
  #prefix: /api
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
  routes:
    mgmt:
      path: /test/abc/mgmt/**
      url: https://myserver:8080/{id}/
```

I want to replace id from from data received from client. As of now I am unable to read 'url' configured in the routes, in the filter may be I am not using the right API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for posting looks like I can get URL and other route attributes by autowiring

```
RouteLocator routeLocator;
```